# How do I use Cognito with Express-gateway for token validation

Tags: jwt, architecture, microservices, amazon-cognito, express-gateway

I have drafted the following architecture

[image: Proposed architechture]

I'm having issues on the validate JWT part on the gateway (Not sure if this is how it's supposed to work).

From what I understand, when a request gets to the gateway, Express Gateway does the JWT validation against the credentials we've set up in the config.

Here is a snippet of ***gateway.config.yml***:

```
policies:
  - proxy
  - logging
  - jwt
  - oauth2

pipelines:
  service1:
    apiEndpoints:
      - service1
    policies:
      - logging:
      - oauth2:
          - action:
              - jwt:
                  subject: 'cognito-app-client-id'
                  algorithms: [ 'alg' ]
                  checkCredentialExistence: false/true
                  issuer: 'cognito-issuer'
                  secretOrPublicKey: 'pub key from cognito'
                  audience: 'cognito-app-client-id'
                  clientId: 'cognito-app-client-id'
                  clientSecret: 'cognito-app-client-secret'
```

Note that **secretOrPublicKey** was retrieved from this URL: ***[https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json](https://cognito-idp.%7Bregion%7D.amazonaws.com/%7BuserPoolId%7D/.well-known/jwks.json)*** and it returned the following:

```
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "alg": "",
            "e": "",
            "kid": "",
            "kty": "",
            "n": "",
            "use": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

To test my endpoint, I made the following request to the gateway including the JWT I got from Cognito.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://mygateway/service1' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyYg...' \
--data ''
```

However I get a ***401 (Unauthorized)***.

Somewhere, somehow, I'm missing something. I just don't know if I'm misunderstanding the whole flow, or I'm not setting up my config properly.

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm possibly missing, or the possible solution?

Comment: What’s the output form `eg credentials list`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to fix the issue.

Fetch my Cognito app-client **JWK** from this URL: [https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json](https://cognito-idp.%7Bregion%7D.amazonaws.com/%7BuserPoolId%7D/.well-known/jwks.json)

Response:

```
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "alg": "",
            "e": "",
            "kid": "",
            "kty": "",
            "n": "",
            "use": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Convert the **JWK** to a **.pem** file (there are online tools for
this), but for confidentiality purposes, I wrote this python script
to do the conversion:

```
import json
from jwcrypto import jwk

jwk_data = {
            "alg": "replace with actual value from jwk",
            "e": "replace with actual value from jwk",
            "kid": "replace with actual value from jwk",
            "kty": "replace with actual value from jwk",
            "n": "replace with actual value from jwk",
            "use": "replace with actual value from jwk"
        }

key = jwk.JWK(**jwk_data)
public_key = key.export_to_pem()

with open('public_key.pem', 'wb') as pem_file:
    pem_file.write(public_key)
```

Of course you'll need to install **jwcrypto** with

> python3 -m pip install jwcrypto

After generating the **.pem** file, I updated my gateway.config.yml
as follow:

```
pipelines:
service1:
  apiEndpoints:
    - service1
  policies:
    - logging:
    - jwt:
        - action:
            secretOrPublicKeyFile: cert/public_key.pem  #cert is the folder where my .pem file is located.
            checkCredentialExistence: false
    - service1:
```

Making a cURL request to the gateway with the correct JWT now returns the desired output.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://mygateway/service1' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyYg...' \
--data ''
```